# intellij's swing plugin in maven project

Tags: java, maven, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Similar questions has been asked but no good answers and nothing that worked for me ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611378/contentpane-cannot-be-null-when-using-ideas-content-designer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887309/swing-gui-with-intellij-error-contentpane-cannot-be-set-to-null-when-compilin), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736420/intellij-contentpane-cannot-be-set-to-null-using-swing-designer)).

In my `Maven`'s project, I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA`'s `UI designer` and every once in a while I'm getting (maybe it have something to do with me running maven clean & install)

```
"contentPane cannot be set to null."
```

To fix it I simply change the panel name using the UI designer, but this solution is not good for running a jar made of my code, and I'm trying to understand the problem and find a more permanent solution.

As you can see below, I haven't checked the "Custom Create" box, and as far as I know, it means that the designer is automatically initializing it (otherwise renaming the panel won't fix it).

#### swing frame

```java
public class MyFrame extends JDialog {
    private JPanel contentPanel;
    .
    .
    .

    private MyFrame() {
        setContentPane(contentPanel);
        .
        .

    }
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>ideauidesigner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javac2</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
.
.
.
</build>
```

#### Component Tree

[image]

Comment: If possible please prepare and provide a small project sample here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191465 . What build system do you use?

Comment: the build system I use is `maven` and I can show you a sample code but it happening in all of my frames and they are pretty basic so I don't think it will help

Comment: @EgorKlepikov do you think "maven clean" may cause this?